# Extracting class representing parent generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I’m working with an interface that defines a single generic parameter.  I have a class that implements that interface and ultimately I need to create a variable of type `Class<? extends MyInterface<?>>` using that implementation.   But it seems I can only do that under very specific circumstances.  Below is a quick code snippet that demonstrates the issue:

```
public class Testing {
    //This won't compile, I'm getting the following error
    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Testing.MyImpl> to Class<? extends Testing.MyInterface<?>>
    Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> type = MyImpl.class;
    
    //This won't compile, I'm getting the following error
    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Testing.MyImpl> to Class<? extends Testing.MyInterface<?>>
    Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> type2 = MyImpl2.class;
    
    //This compiles
    Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> type3 = MyImpl3.class;

    public static interface MyInterface<T> { }
    
    public static class MyImpl<T extends Object> implements MyInterface<T>{ }
    
    public static class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface{ }
    
    public static class MyImpl3 implements MyInterface<Object>{ }
}
```

I get `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Testing.MyImpl> to Class<? extends Testing.MyInterface<?>>"`
I really need an implementation like MyImpl that defines its own generic but I need to pass the MyImpl.class value to an annotation that expects the value to be of type  `Class<? extends MyInterface<?>>` So I can do a simple cast to solve the complication problem. (Attempting to do so results in `The value for annotation attribute Type.value must be a class literal`)

Is there any generic's magic I can do to make `Class<? extends MyInterface<?>> type = MyImpl.class;` compile, without having to cast it?

I'm using Java 17.

Thank you for looking at this!